# Ajuda para fazer operação matemática de divisão de dois selects

Tags: mysql, divisão

Estou precisando calcular a porcentagem(%) com esses dois selects, já fiz a multiplicação do primeiro por 100, preciso agora pegar esse resultado e dividir pelo segundo select para ter o valor 95,34.

Tentei fazer com esse Union mas ele traz uma coluna com os dois resultados.
[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94o0G.png)

```
With total as(
select COUNT(*)*100 as valor from glpi_tickets where solvedate >= DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW() ), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY) AND DATE > DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW() ), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY) 
union
select COUNT(*) as valor from glpi_tickets where DATE > DATE_SUB( DATE( NOW() ), INTERVAL DAY( NOW() ) -1 DAY)
)
Select * from total;
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Para calcular a porcentagem com base nos resultados dos dois selects, você pode usar uma subconsulta dentro da sua query principal. Aqui está como você pode fazer isso:

```
WITH total AS (
    SELECT
        (COUNT(*) * 100) AS total_solved,
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM glpi_tickets WHERE DATE > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 1 DAY)) AS total_tickets
    FROM
        glpi_tickets
    WHERE
        solvedate >= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 1 DAY)
        AND DATE > DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAY(NOW()) - 1 DAY)
)
SELECT
    total_solved / total_tickets AS percentage
FROM
    total;
```

Esta consulta calcula o número total de tickets resolvidos e o número total de tickets, depois divide o número total de tickets resolvidos pelo número total de tickets para obter a porcentagem. Isso deve dar o resultado que você está procurando.